# apache user and permissions for document roots

Tags: php, linux, apache, security, permissions

I think this is not too specific, in fact I think it's a very common problem. But I didn't find any threads giving a solution to the following.

I want to run website1 and website2 on a server.
Each virtual host has its own Document in **/var/www/website1/web/** and **/var/www/website2/web/**

Permissions are set like this: **rwx rwx r-x**

Owner of both folders is: **somedeveloperuser**
Group of both folders is: **www-data**

I want PHP scripts in **/var/www/website1/web/** to have write access to **/var/www/website1/web/**

EDITED:
What could be a good practice to **forbid** a script in **/var/www/website1/web/** write access to **/var/www/website2/web/** or any other folder grouped by **www-data**?

I am asking because I don't want any site, which could be in some way insecure to harm other website folders.

Thank you for reading and helping!

Comment: `chown -R somedev:www-data /var/www/website1/web/` and `chmod 777 /var/www/website1/web/`

Comment: You are saying you want `website1` to have write access to `website2` but not allow one website to harm other websites? Because if 1 has access to write to 2, then it can put whatever it wants in 2, even if harmful or not.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks. Of cource I meant to forbid, not permit. Sorry

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The answer though would depend on how "bullet proof" you need it to be. If you are hosting just a few semi-trusted users (like corporate and a ToS) then you might be able to get away with just setting up a php basedir setting for each virtual host. This will cover most php functions but is far from "bullet proof". If you are starting your own shared hosting and letting any knucklehead with notepad access, you would probably want to look into setting up suexec which allows for separate users per virtual host and just set the owners appropriately.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the following: website1 could be a wordpress cms, some wp-user would install a plugin, which could be insecure. That would be an entrypoint for injecting a PHP script, that could harm folders or files in /var/www/website2/, right? So, if I want to be secure, I should use something like suexec, even I don't start a shared hosting?

Comment: honestly, yes. I would personally setup fastcgi with suexec because that would allow for maximum security. However, like I said, open_basedir might be enough. It essentially stops php functions from accessing anything outside the document root and usually a temp directory. Where you run into trouble is that people can call stuff like exec and pass it any path the php user has access to and you can't really stop that. You could disable running shell/exec functions as well and that might be enough. There are a thousand ways I probably don't know about to get around it though.

Comment: Using suexec would rely on the user system of the OS and allow for maximum security. Each virtual host would have it's own user and that would be the user for the document root. You could even allow ftp access then and have that be the same ftp user.

Comment: Again thank you for the explanation! It feels like relying on the user system and well set up permissions system wide in combination with suexec giving access to document roots by individual users fits the best for my needs. OK!